# How do I change the color of a row based on specific dates?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The problem that I currently have is, I'm trying to change the color of a row based on a specific date. If the date in the column is less than `TODAY()` then the row should be `Blue`, and if is greater `TODAY()` then the row should be `White`.

So far I have tried the conditional formatting for it, and it works on a row to row basis but, what I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to make it go across the entire sheet. So for example, if a person adds another row, the condition automatically applies to the new row based on that row inputted date.

The current code that I have tried is a conditional format that is highlighting the row with the following code:

`=IF($H$2 > TODAY(), TRUE, FALSE)`

Where `H` is the column of the dates that are manually inputted in by the individual, and highlighting that row. That does work, as I have tested it, but then I would have to do that condition for every row afterwards including new rows that are added into the sheet.

What the results look like currently:
[image: Condtional_Formating]

Is there a way to dynamically change specific rows based on date so even if the user inserts a new row, that condition applies to all and only those specific rows that have a date greater than `TODAY()`?

I have tried the following code but doesn't work properly for what I'm trying to accomplish:

`=IF($H$2:$H$7>TODAY(),TRUE,FALSE)`

Which the result looks like:
[image: Conditional Formatting 2]

When I want the results to look like the previous image. Is there a way of doing this or would it have to be a row by row conditioning to make this work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you really need to do is to remove the `$` in front of the row. Then it's a relative reference, so the conditional formatting will consider `$H2`, `$H3`, and so on.

Also note that the `IF` and `TRUE` or `FALSE` are redundant; you can simplify to

```
=$H2>TODAY()
```

[image]